# Is there a legal way for a country to gain territory from another through a referendum?

Tags: international-law, international, territory

I was wondering if there's a historical precedent for this. Russia gained territory, but it did so after invading it and using the referendum as a way to convince it was justified. Puerto Rico was a whole country. I am wondering if there's a historical precedent or a legal basis for it to be done without war.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proposed_political_status_for_Puerto_Rico

Comment: This paper seems to be highly relevant.  http://www.iandrinstitute.org/docs/Sussman-When-the-Demos-Shapes-the-Polis-IRI.pdf

Comment: I don't see how Puerto Rico is relevant here as thy are already a territory of the US and there is no talk of them changing that and joining a different country.

Comment: Q might use some cleanup to avoid "triggering" downvotes - which may include clarifying how Porto Rico is relevant, but it seems reasonable enough to ask.  +1  As the point as been made by John Dallman, it is possible, *provided* the initial "emitting" country is willing, **without external coercion** (cough, Russia, cough), to honor a secession referendum.  Then, to a large extent, it becomes the business of the seceded territory *and the receiving state* to figure it out.    The take away is, for anyone upset about RU sympathies: **RU is very far  away from any kind of legitimacy here.**

Comment: "Legal" may be the wrong word here, since there's no binding global authority that signs off on such things. "Internationally recognized as legitimate" would be more realistic.

Comment: Russia didn't gain territory, but it militarily occupies part of the territory. Russia may claims it "integrated" them, even without having them under their control, but if nobody seriously acknowledges your territorial claims, they're quite irrelevant. Your question sounds very much troll like, you wanna get out a statement that is BS with a valid question, implicitly validating the BS claim.

Comment: @jeffronicus I agree in principle. But there is the U.N. which arguably can give legitimacy for re-ordering borders, a need that typically arises after turmoil like (civil) wars or with failed states. At least they give legitimacy to an (armed) intervention with that goal. But of course -- the point you make -- they have zero enforcement or actual authority.

Comment: One can imagine genocidal regimes which would justify or even demand (because of an "emergency" or a state of "duress", in German *übergesetzlicher Notstand*) intervention  and violation of a nation's sovereignty, including its territorial integrity.

Answer (score 26):

As a result of the [Paris Peace Conference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris_Peace_Conference_(1919%E2%80%931920)) that ended the First World War, there were a whole slew of referendums held to decide which country a territory should belong to:

- Germany/Denmark: In [Schleswig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1920_Schleswig_plebiscites), plebiscites were held seperately for Northern Schleswig, which voted to become Danish, Central Schleswig and the southern Zone, which both voted to remain German.
- Germany/Poland: In [Upper Silesia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1921_Upper_Silesia_plebiscite) a plebiscite voted to remain with Germany/Prussia, but the inter-Allied Commission decided to divide the region and award part of the territory to Poland.
- Germany/Poland: In [Eastern Prussia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1920_East_Prussian_plebiscite), two plebiscites were conducted for the administrative areas of Allenstein and Marienwerder. Both voted to remain part of Germany/Prussia.
- Germany/France: In the [Saar territory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1935_Saar_status_referendum), the plebiscite was held only in 1935, the region being administered as a protectorate of the League of Nations for the years inbetween. The majority voted to return to Germany. Another [referendum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1955_Saar_Statute_referendum) was held after the Second World War, again with the German side winning.
- Belgium/Germany: In the cantons of [Eupen-Malmedy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eupen-Malmedy#Provisional_Belgian_administration,_1919%E2%80%931925) the plebiscite decided to join Belgium.
- Austria/Yugoslavia: The [Southern Carinthians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1920_Carinthian_plebiscite) decided to remain a part of Austria.
- Austria/Hungary: The inhabitants of [Sopron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1921_Sopron_plebiscite) and a number of surrounding settlements voted to join Hungary.
- Austria/Switzerland: The population of [Vorarlberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorarlberg#History) was asked whether it wanted to negotiate an accession to the Swiss confederation. Although the result was a Yes, the Swiss side did refuse, and nothing came of it.

*Far more territories changed nationality as a result of the war without the population being asked. Some plebiscites (Tirol, Salzburg) were held, but were not accepted as legitimate by the parties of the treaties. A plebiscite about the independence of Kurdistan had been part of the provisions of the Treaty of Sèvres, but was never held.*

Answer (score 24):

The only way for this to be legal is if the country loosing the territory is willing to cede it to the country that acquires it. This happens from time to time, typically to [simplify borders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/India%E2%80%93Bangladesh_enclaves) that have been made complicated by history. Carrying out the transfer requires a treaty between the countries.

For example, the UK has expressed willingness to cede Northern Ireland to Éire if the population of Northern Ireland are in favour of it, as part of the Belfast Agreement. That opinion would presumably be established via a referendum. However, that referendum would not intrinsically be binding on the UK government. The legislation creating the referendum *might* make the result binding, but that's a matter of the content of that particular piece of hypothetical legislation.

For the current example of eastern territories of Ukraine, Russia cannot create an enforceable right to the territory via any kind of referendum. Russia is well known to manipulate the results of its own elections. Holding a referendum in territory that is occupied  by a poorly disciplined army means the results wouldn't be credible even if Russia was honestly trying to get an accurate answer. It's meaningless anyway without Ukraine's consent, so holding the referendum just makes Russia look worse.

Comment: It's not really about Russian electoral credibility, such as it is.  Holding a secession referendum has to be freely accepted by Ukraine first.

Comment: The UK government hasn't just "expressed a general willingness" to cede Northern Ireland to the Republic of Ireland should that be the wish of the people of both Northern Ireland and the Republic, it has made a legal commitment to do so via the Belfast Agreement.

Comment: Nitpick: If using the Irish name for the Irish state rather than calling it _(Republic of) Ireland_, it’s quite important to remember the _fada_ and write it _Éire_. The name _Eire_ was formerly used by the UK government (but hasn’t been for over 70 years), but has never been used in Ireland and is not used anywhere anymore – it is also a particularly unfortunate form, since _eire_ in Irish means ‘burden’!

Comment: There are plenty of examples in History where a stronger country forced another to cede territory, with a local referendum or without. A recent example is Yougoslavia, which got broken down against its will. Self-determination is a cardinal right of modern international law, so the *only* legal question here is whether the people of Crimea and Eastern Territories really wanted to become independent or not? Half of the world thinks so, and once independent they had the right to ask to be part of Russia.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica This goes against international law and the right to self-determination. Few colonies would have won their independence otherwise.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet nitpick: Ireland is an island not a country so it needs to be Republic of Ireland without the brackets :-)

Comment: @Shautieh "Once independent"? While occupied by a foreign army?

Comment: @deep64blue _Ireland_ is the official English _name_ of the state as defined in the constitution (1937); ‘Republic of Ireland’ is the official _description_ as defined in the Republic of Ireland Act (1948). So both are correct names to refer to the state, hence the brackets; but it’s true that _Republic of Ireland_ is often used to disambiguate from the island (which has no other common name). On the other hand, there is no name for the Irish state that isn’t controversial in one way or another, so whatever you do, you’re damned.

Comment: Not only would the referendum not be enough to cede the territory in your NI example, the enacting legislation wouldn't be enough either.  You'd need a treaty between the two parties so that the other side can formally accept or reject it.  In some cases, the other country may not *want* that territory (e.g., you can't unilaterally make that toxic Superfund site someone else's problem so that you don't have to pay to clean it up).

Comment: @bta: fair point, added.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Really interesting footnote, but in the interest of compatibility one needs to accept that diacritics, especially accents, should be reasonably omittable due to certain keyboards/encoding sets not allowing for them. The meaning of "eire" is unfortunate but that does not put the onus on the rest of the world to be actively aware of it nor actively take more precaution than for any other diacritic.

Comment: @MatthewWells well, yes? Otherwise the USA would still be part of the UK (French army being there), colonies in Africa and Asia wouldn't have become independent (most of them were helped by USSR, China and others). Yougoslavia was broken apart under American bombs. Need the list go on?

Comment: @Flater That’s why the state also has a common English name (well, several). Similar to how you wouldn’t write _Island_ or _Foroyar_ in English – you’d either use the English names _Iceland_ and _Faroe Islands_, or you’d use the local names with diacritics and write _Ísland_ and _Føroyar_. And then there’s the whole recent _Türkiye_ issue…

Answer (score 11):

The principle of self-determination is recognized under international law and includes the right of peoples to choose their own political status and pursue their economic, social, and cultural development freely (International Covenant on Civil and Political Rights, Article 1; International Covenant on Economic, Social and Cultural Rights, Article 1; United Nations General Assembly Resolution 2625 (XXV)). However, the exercise of this right is subject to certain conditions, including respect for the territorial integrity of existing states, the absence of coercion or manipulation, and the absence of discrimination against minorities (International Court of Justice, Advisory Opinion on the Accordance with International Law of the Unilateral Declaration of Independence in Respect of Kosovo).

If a proposed referendum would affect the territorial integrity of an existing state, the legal framework and procedures for conducting the referendum are critical. The legal framework would depend on the domestic laws of the state concerned, as well as any relevant international agreements or norms that apply. The Venice Commission's Code of Good Practice on Referendums provides guidance on the legal framework and procedures for conducting referendums.

There have been historical precedents for the use of referendums to resolve territorial disputes, such as the 2014 referendum on Scottish independence from the United Kingdom. The referendum was conducted in accordance with the Scottish Independence Referendum (Franchise) Act 2013 and the Scottish Independence Referendum Act 2013. The referendum was also subject to international scrutiny, with the Organization for Security and Cooperation in Europe (OSCE) sending observers to monitor the process (OSCE Final Report on the Scottish Independence Referendum).

However, the use of a referendum to determine territorial status is not a panacea and may not always be a fair or appropriate mechanism for resolving territorial disputes. In some cases, alternative mechanisms such as negotiation, mediation, or international adjudication may be more appropriate.

Comment: This looks like a reasonable enough answer, but Territorial Dispute isn't all that relevant to the OP's question (yes, even though they mentioned Ukraine).  And it really isn't relevant to Scotland, which isn't claimed by anyone else.  You can have a secession movement wo territorial dispute (Catalonia) and you can have a territorial dispute wo secession aims (empty land).  You can have both (Crimea?, Kashmir) but they dont necessarily go together, your Scottish example being a case of no TD.  Still, upvoted, my TD remark doesnt negate the overall quality of answer.

Answer (score 3):

There is precedent for a country peacefully splitting into parts, for example  the [Dissolution of Czechoslovakia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissolution_of_Czechoslovakia)

There is also precedent of countries peacefully uniting, for example the [German reunification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_reunification)

So it would be perfectly legal and possible for a country to split of a part and that part merging with another country.

Please note that "peacefully" here also means with no armed goons standing in polling places watching you. Peacefully means "no guns", not "no guns fired where foreign media can see it" as with the Russian "referendums".

Comment: Of course both of these cases are consensual on both sides. One caveat: There are cases where countries are forbidden from merging because of international obligations; e.g. Austria was forbidden from uniting with Germany in treaties after both world wars.

Answer (score 1):

**No**, it is illegal for a country to take action of gaining the territory from another country through initiating the referendum.

This question may be related to the recent sentences of Sergey Lavrov, claiming that UN has the foreseen rules when a referendum could be held for changing the territorial integrity of the State. There is no such.

> 4. All Members shall refrain in their international relations from the
>    threat or use of force against the territorial integrity or political
>    independence of any state, or in any other manner inconsistent with
>    the Purposes of the United Nations.

And this the only chapter in the [United Nations Charter](https://www.un.org/en/about-us/un-charter/full-text) where the "territorial integrity" is mentioned at all. It is not about the interpretation of the rules, there are no other relevant rules to interpret, as much as exactly a country is considered.

There are some additional old rules relevant to the liberation of colonies and other "not self governed" territories. Sergey Lavrov is likely attempting to push that Crimea and other annexed territories used to be kind of a colony of Ukraine, but this looks quite questionable as colony is a territory subject to a form of foreign rule, and these regions did not have such a special status (they citizens were free to elect the President and the like). See [StopFake.org](https://www.stopfake.org/ru/lavrov-popytalsya-opravdat-agressiyu-protiv-ukrainy-ssylkoj-na-nesushhestvuyushhij-tezis-iz-dokumentov-oon/).

Comment: But they're free to negotiate, e.g. if Austria wanted Bavaria and thought Bavaria did likewise, it could negotiate with the German government to hold a referendum, but Germany would have to give permission.

Comment: True, but it is legal to push people in the contested territory to revolt and fight for independence, in order to then make a deal with them to be part of your country.

Comment: "Push people" is too vague. There's a world of difference between speaking in support of political change, and sending your troops in to pretend to be local forces to start a genocide. Not all methods of "push"ing are "legal"

Comment: The same can be said about all the colour revolutions pushed by the USA, and many others. Sending troups to kill and pillage in the name of democracy is not more "legal" yet the USA does this in weaker countries without much backslash.

Comment: You cannot really say that everything USA or "many others" has ever done automatically becomes legal as per scope of the question. There are in average 44 murders per day in USA alone, this does not make the murder legal.

Comment: @Shautieh "The same can be said about all the colour revolutions pushed by the USA, and many others. Sending troups to kill and pillage in the name of democracy is not more "legal" yet the USA does this in weaker countries without much backslash. " That might be a coherent thought, if the US sent their troops to kill and pillage in color revolutions. Fairly sure the only recent "color revolution" the US sent forces to assist was Libya. And that was the execution of a UN resolution. The US giving vocal support is nothing like Russia taking Crimea with unmarked troops.

Comment: (And that force's mandate was to prevent the sack of Benghazi)

Comment: @bharring Russians have a different approach indeed, and they don't mind sending unmarked troops whereas the American way would be to send intelligence officers along with special agents that will recruit, train and arm local extremists that will then follow American orders to overthrow the local government. The result is similar, and arguing which method is preferable is not what's important.

Comment: When your democratically elected "local extremists" are being genocided by invading Russian tanks, giving them anti-tank weapons isn't the same as Russian subjugation. America has certainly done bad, but it hasn't annexed territory in a century. It's last border change ceded territory. It's not American orders that make Eastern Europe not want to be Russian.